# Special characters are properly displayed in Eclipse but not in .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, special-characters, executable-jar

This is my very first question on Stackoverflow.

I have developed a tool in Eclipse that receives an Excel file (.xls) and adds the content of some cells to a JList. The problem is when exporting the project to a Runnable JAR file, as all the special characters are shown as "�" in the JList. However, they are properly displayed when running the application from the IDE. Please help ^^

OS: macOS High Sierra (v.10.13.1)
Eclipse: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: Plesse read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and check your file enoding settings

Comment: @Marged - hey there! The one I need to use is ISO-8859-1 - is that what you were referring to?

Comment: The cause is having a Unicode symbol that has no corresponding bytes in the target charset. ISO-8859-1 has no comma-like quotes for instance. Then a place holder � is generated. Maybe your IDE is set to UTF-8 which can do all, whereas the program code just uses the current platform charset, where it should have specified it.

Comment: @JoopEggen Can you please speak English? How do I set my IDE to ISO-8859-1 instead of UFT-8? I have tried so many things... ty in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So far I have tried the following -

1. Run - Run Configurations - Common - Encoding - ISO-8859-1
2. Run - Debug Configurations -  Common - Encoding - ISO-8859-1
3. Eclipse - Preferences - General - Workspace - Text file encoding - ISO-8859-1
4. Even I went to the Eclipse folder and modified the file called "eclipse.ini"

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

By adding the following line:
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");

Comment: Where did u add this line?